# make model __unicode__ method return to multiple columns

Tags: python, django

How can I make Django model `__unicode__` method return multiple values to multiple columns?

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more explicit. The `__unicode__` method can return whatever you like, as long as it's unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

What you can do, is create another method and add that in `list_display`. From its [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), `list_display` can take four kinds of values:

1. A field of the model
2. A callable (a function, or a lambda) that will take a model instance.
3. The name of an attribute of the model class (this can be any function in the model class).
4. The name of an attribute of the `ModelAdmin` class

For your case, we need to use #3, in your `models.py`:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   # etc, etc.

   def __unicode__(self):
       return unicode(self.name)

   def something_else(self):
       return self.another_field
```

In the `admin.py`

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['__unicode__', 'something_else']

admin.site.register(SomeModel, SomeModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4):

just add to following to the Class:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.value1, self.value2)
```